# Were can I find the Depreciation for Microsoft (MSFT)?

Tags: sec, financial-statements, depreciation

I looked at the financial statements for MSFT. I am trying to find the depreciation in the operating expenses, but it seems they did not disclose the information. Did I look at the the right place? Where do I find that information?

Comment: "I looked at the financial statements for MSFT" — Could you share the link you used to look at the financial statements?

Comment: @Flux Yes, this link https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=789019&accession_number=0001564590-22-026876&xbrl_type=v# and that one as well https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/MSFT/income-statement. Look at the income statement.

Comment: @J.Doe why would you be looking for depreciation on the income statement?

Answer (score 1):

The depreciation expense is disclosed in *NOTE 7 — PROPERTY AND EQUIPMENT* of [Microsoft's 2022 Form 10-K filing](https://microsoft.gcs-web.com/static-files/07cf3c30-cfc3-4567-b20f-f4b0f0bd5087):

> During fiscal years 2022, 2021, and 2020, depreciation expense was $12.6 billion, $9.3 billion, and $10.7 billion, respectively.

I'm not sure why there's no line item for it in the income statement. Perhaps someone will write a better answer to explain that.

Comment: It shows up on balance sheets and cash flow statements. Why would it be on income statement?

Comment: @littleadv "Why would it be on income statement?" — Isn't depreciation usually shown in the income statement? It is an expense.

Comment: Their income statement is very highlevel. Depreciating is hiding in the R&D and operating expenses, they refer you to the notes. Which is what you referred to in your answer as well.

Comment: @littleadv Thank you for the information. Yes, ASC 730-10-25-2 allows the depreciation expense of R&D equipment and facilities to be included in R&D expenses. However, Microsoft presumably owns non-R&D buildings and equipment. In which income statement line item do non-R&D-related depreciation appear?

Comment: As I said - operating expenses. `General and administrative` they call it. It could also be in `Cost of revenue` section as well.